# How to reduce spacing between navigation links CSS

Tags: css, squarespace

so here's my question... so close to finishing some css, an issue lies in closing up the space between 'series' and 'portfolios' on my Squarespace site. Just one little thing left!! I've attached a photo... any ideas how??

[image: website]

Many thanks in advance!

EDIT:

This is the entire code that I have in the custom CSS box.

```css
#header #logoWrapper, 
 #header #siteTitleWrapper { 
     position: relative; 
     left: 15%; 
     -webkit-transform: translate(-50%,0); 
     -moz-transform: translate(-50%,0); 
     -ms-transform: translate(-50%,0); 
     -o-transform: translate(-50%,0); 
     transform: translate(-50%,0); 
     text-align: right !important;
 }#sitetitle { text-align: left }

 #header #mainNavWrapper .index { 
     margin: 0 0 0 100px !important; 
     text-align: left !important;
 }
```

Comment: No code? No links to a live environment? A picture is *not* a proper substitute for a crystal ball.

Comment: Please go read [ask].

Comment: Edited with the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I would remove the CSS you wrote (included in your question), as it's bound to cause problems at different widths and on different devices. It's quite problematic.

Instead, try using the following CSS which minimally overrides Squarespace's default rules, is easily adjusted, won't affect the mobile navigation, and should be more stable across different platforms.

```
/*Media query prevents messing up mobile nav.*/
@media only screen and (min-width: 769px) {
    #header {
        padding-left: 10%;
        /*Adjust this as desired. Default is 30px, but looks like you have more than that in your screenshot.*/
    }
    #headerNav {
        margin-left: 6% !important;
        /*Adjust as desired. Going more than this may result in wrapped nav at ~750px.*/
    }
    #header #logoWrapper,
    #header #siteTitleWrapper {
        display: inline-block;
        position: static;
        transform: none;
        text-align: left;
    }
    #header #logoWrapper,
    #header #siteTitleWrapper,
    #header #headerNav {
        display: inline-block;
        margin-top: 0 !important;
        margin-bottom: 0 !important;
    }
    .expand-homepage-index-links #headerNav .index.home,
    .expand-homepage-index-links #showOnScrollWrapper .index.home {
        margin-right: 0 !important;
        margin-left: 0 !important;
    }
    #header .folder {
        margin-left: 0 !important;
        margin-right: 0 !important;
    }
}
```

Comment: Excellent improve! Many thanks!!! But I still have the problem with the space, what I want would be this: http://oi65.tinypic.com/tan709.jpg I've edited the pic with Paint because I really don't know how to implement the code in CSS... Maybe there's an option in the code above but I cannot find it.

Comment: And what does it look like now? A link to the page would be better than an image.

Comment: This is the webpage http://marknolanphoto.com/ . Sorry for not posting it before.

Comment: Thanks for the link; it's much easier that way. I have updated my answer, adding 4 new lines of CSS to the bottom. Using this updated answer should fix your issue.